# How can one define the quantum interferometric power in the case of a multiparametric system using the quantum Fisher information matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, fisher-information

please, was the quantum interferometric power defined in the case of a multiparametric system? I know that in the case of a single parameter, the quantum interferometric power is defined as the minimization of the Fisher information, where the minimum is intended for all Hamiltonians with a given spectrum, with a normalization factor of 1/4 for more convenience. But in situations where more than a parameter is involved, the relevant object in the estimation problem is given by the so-called quantum Fisher information matrix. How can one define the interferometric power? Also, if we diagonalize this matrix, does this give a link at the level of quantum correlations?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).